# Spring Boot - Spring Data JPA - Rest/Json - How to custom the output to include or not the Collection for @OneToMany?

Tags: json, spring-boot, rest, spring-data-jpa, jackson

For `Spring Boot` working with `Spring Data` for a **uni-directional** `@OneToMany` relation,
such as `Parent` and `Child`, their codes are respectively as follows:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="parent")
public class Parent implements Serializable {

    ...

    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    @OrderBy("id")
    private final Set<Child> children = new LinkedHashSet<>();

    ...

}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name="child")
public class Child implements Serializable {

    ...

}
```

And having a custom `ParentRepository` interface extending `CrudRepository<T,ID>`, it has defined explicitly a custom method named `findByIdWithChildren` working with `@Query` and using `JOIN FETCH`

Therefore using Spring MVC - through HTML (`Thymeleaf`) - through `@GetMapping` is possible:

**Group I**

- (A) Find and show **only** a specific `Parent` - through the default `findById` method. (Ok)
- (B) Find and show a specific `Parent` with all its `Child` - through the *custom* `findByIdWithChildren` method. (Ok)
- (C) Find and show **only** all the `Parent` - through the default `findAll` method. (Ok)

Therefore until here all is Ok. The problem is when `REST` is used, exists now the following behavior as follows.

**Group II**

- (A) behaves as (B) *Group I* (Not desired)
- (B) behaves as (B) *Group I* (Ok)
- (C) Find and show all the `Parent` **but** with all their `Child` (Not desired)

Using `@JsonBackReference` as follows

```
    @JsonBackReference
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.REMOVE, orphanRemoval=true)
    @JoinColumn(name="parent_id")
    @OrderBy("id")
    private final Set<Child> children = new LinkedHashSet<>();
```

happens as follows:

**Group III**

- (A) Find and show **only** a specific `Parent` - through the default `findById` method. (OK)
- (B) Find and show a specific `Parent` **but without** all its `Child` - through the *custom* `findByIdWithChildren` method. (Not desired)
- (C) Find and show **only** all the `Parent` - through the default `findAll` method. (OK)

**Question**

- How to reach the same kind of output for Rest as HTML?

Show only a specific parent (without its children), show a specific parent with its children, show only all the parents (without their children)